# Calculate daily targets based on monthly targets Sales Power bi

Tags: sql-server, ssas, powerbi, dax, powerquery

I had the following question which I just can't wrap my head around it to do it in a neat way.

I want to create a line graph with three lines. We call it a budget snake.

[image]

- Created sales orders (black)
- Invoiced orders  (green)
- Daily targets (red)

This per salesperson. The creation of this graph for the created and invoiced orders is easy as these are all on a daily granularity so creating the line graph is easy.

I just struggle how to create/generate such a line for the targets. 
In this case, I manually created a table with date - salesperson - daily target
Eg.

[image]

Which is very cumbersome. What I would like to be able to do is 
create a table on a monthly level for each salesperson and that
PowerBI can "generate/calculate" the daily target in such a way that
I can graph the red line without all the hassle of creating it for
each salesperson manually.

The input would be something like this

```
+-----------+----------+--------------+--------+----------------+--------------+---------------+
|   Date    |  Month   | Salesperson  | Branch | Monthly Target | Daily Target | Business days |
+-----------+----------+--------------+--------+----------------+--------------+---------------+
| 1/01/2017 | January  | salesperson1 | test   |          73529 |         4325 |            17 |
| 1/02/2017 | February | salesperson1 | test   |          73529 |         4325 |            20 |
+-----------+----------+--------------+--------+----------------+--------------+---------------+
```

I have a date dimension table so on my graph I have the date as the x-axis and then the runningorders/runningsales as the y-axis but I would something like a daily runningtarget so that the red line is nicely going with the orders and sales.

I had a look at this pattern but I just cannot figure out how this can generate
a line graph.

https://www.daxpatterns.com/budget-patterns/

So somehow, I guess I would need something which generates this first table with the second table as input. I tried some measures in Dax but none of them give me the cumulative steps for each day. It mostly just shows me the value.

These are the measures I use for the other lines. This works nicely when changing the date filters. 
Running sales

```
RunningTotalSales = CALCULATE(sum(vw_invoice_trn_summary[NetInvoiceValue]),
                     FILTER(ALLSELECTED(DimTime),DimTime[Date] <= MAX(DimTime[Date])))
```

Running orders

```
RunningTotalOrders = CALCULATE(sum(vw_orders_raised[OrderTotal]),FILTER(ALLSELECTED(DimTime),DimTime[Date] <= MAX(DimTime[Date])))
```

In my current manual solution, the full year though does not work well with the targets line as I am not sure I do it right.

[image]

**UPDATE**

So thinking further about this. It feels like I just need to be able to create a table with a date - daily target - salesperson. based on the monthly targets but not sure how you can do that in power bi. Ideally, you can just add/remove a salesperson and that specific table gets regenerated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have two solutions to this. One using DAX and one using the query editor.

---

**DAX Solution:**

**1.** Create a calendar table that has all the dates you need.

If `Targets` is the table containing your monthly targets, create a new table using a formula like this:

```
Calendar = CALENDAR(EOMONTH(MIN(Targets[Date]),-1)+1,EOMONTH(MAX(Targets[Date]),0))
```

**2.** Create a new table `DailyTargets` as a cross join of your dates and salespersons.

The `CROSSJOIN` function creates a row for each date and salesperson combination:

```
DailyTargets = CROSSJOIN(VALUES('Calendar'[Date]),VALUES(Targets[Salesperson]))
```

**3.** Create a calculated column for your daily targets.

I do this by looking up the monthly target and dividing by the number of days in the month:

```
DailyTarget = DIVIDE(
    LOOKUPVALUE(Targets[MonthlyTarget],
                Targets[Month], FORMAT(DailyTargets[Date],"mmmm"),
                Targets[Salesperson], DailyTargets[Salesperson]),
    DAY(EOMONTH(DailyTargets[Date],0)))
```

Now you have a daily target for each date and each salesperson.

---

**PowerQuery Solution:**

**1.** Create a calendar table that has all the dates you need.

Create a blank query and use the following code:

```
= List.Dates(List.Min(Targets[Date]),
             Duration.Days(Date.EndOfMonth(List.Max(Targets[Date]))
             - List.Min(Targets[Date])) + 1,
             #duration(1,0,0,0))
```

**2.** Convert this list to a table.

Click on "To Table" under the Transform tab and rename the column from "Column1" to "Date".

**3.** Create a custom column for the month name.

You can use the formula`Date.MonthName([Date])` for this.

**4.** Merge this query with the `Targets` table (joining on the `Month` columns).

**5.** After merging, expand the `Salesperson` and `MonthlyTarget` columns.

**6.** Create the daily target by dividing the monthly target by the number of days in the month.

You can use the formula `[MonthlyTarget]/Date.DaysInMonth([Date])` for this.

The entire query should look like this:

```
let
    Source = List.Dates(List.Min(Targets[Date]), Duration.Days(Date.EndOfMonth(List.Max(Targets[Date])) - List.Min(Targets[Date])) + 1, #duration(1,0,0,0)),
    #"Converted to Table" = Table.FromList(Source, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Converted to Table",{{"Column1", "Date"}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Renamed Columns", "Month", each Date.MonthName([Date])),
    #"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Added Custom",{"Month"},Targets,{"Month"},"Targets",JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    #"Expanded Targets" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "Targets", {"Salesperson", "MonthlyTarget"}, {"Salesperson", "MonthlyTarget"}),
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Expanded Targets", "DailyTarget", each [MonthlyTarget]/Date.DaysInMonth([Date]))
in
    #"Added Custom1"
```

Instead of going step by step, you can just paste this into the Advanced Editor if you'd like. (Just be sure you use whatever table name you have instead of `Targets`.)

Comment: I was working on this, and It has several challenges like extract weekends and accumulate by [Target]

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works for me. So I cross joined it with a date table where I filtered out only the business days. then I used the same measure as for my  running orders/sales and the targets nicely shows up! this is a great solution! So after having all my relations with my date table correctly set the calculations are correct!

Answer (score 2):

I have a much simpler solution for this:

> I just need to be able to create a table with a date - daily target - salesperson. based on the monthly targets

Let's say I have a table like this:

[image]

Where `Month` contains the date for the first day of each month. We then add a custom column "Date" using the query editor menu `(Add Column > Custom Column)`. We paste this formula for our new column:

```
= List.Dates([Month], Date.Day(Date.EndOfMonth([Month])), #duration(1, 0, 0, 0))
```

Each row of the new column will contain a list of all dates within that row's month. Expand that column by clicking on the button on the top right corner and choosing "Expand to new rows".

[image]

Now you have a row for each day, and you can simply add another custom column, "Daily Target", that divides the monthly target by the number of days in each month:

```
= [Monthly Target]/Date.DaysInMonth([Date])
```

And your table is ready:

[image]

Comment: Hi Mcard, Thanks for the suggestion! looks very neat as well. Only thing i was wondering, as always, what if you want to set the daily target based on the amount of working days in that month? Would there be a formula for that with your more straightforward approach?

Comment: Hey Koen, I had found your question when I was going through the same issue so decided I had to share the solution I found! If you think it's a solution, consider upvoting it so that other users can know it works. Apparently there is no straightforward solution for basing the calculation on working days... I recommend looking at this: https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Power-Query-M-code-find-number-of-working-days-between-2-dates/td-p/281608